# unintended lines while using region class (GDI+) in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, graphics, gdi+, graphics2d

I am trying to make a closed graphic object and fill the object with a color using region class in vb.net 2010 (using .net 4.0). the code looks something like this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim gr As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
    gr.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
    Dim mybrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
    Dim lineax1, lineay1, lineax2, lineay2, linebx1, lineby1, linebx2, lineby2 As Integer
    lineax1 = 400 + (280 * Math.Cos(10 * Math.PI / 180))
    lineay1 = 400 + (280 * Math.Sin(10 * Math.PI / 180))
    lineax2 = 400 + (300 * Math.Cos(10 * Math.PI / 180))
    lineay2 = 400 + (300 * Math.Sin(10 * Math.PI / 180))
    linebx1 = 400 + (280 * Math.Cos(55 * Math.PI / 180))
    lineby1 = 400 + (280 * Math.Sin(55 * Math.PI / 180))
    linebx2 = 400 + (300 * Math.Cos(55 * Math.PI / 180))
    lineby2 = 400 + (300 * Math.Sin(55 * Math.PI / 180))
    Dim path1 As GraphicsPath = New GraphicsPath()
    path1.StartFigure()
    path1.AddArc(100.0F, 100.0F, 600.0F, 600.0F, 10.0F, 45.0F)
    path1.AddLine(lineax1, lineay1, lineax2, lineay2)
    path1.AddLine(linebx1, lineby1, linebx2, lineby2)
    path1.AddArc(120.0F, 120.0F, 560.0F, 560.0F, 10.0F, 45.0F)
    path1.CloseFigure()
    Dim rg As Region = New Region(path1)
    gr.FillRegion(mybrush, rg)
End Sub
```

everything works great except the two unintended cross lines (find the image attached). any suggestions to remove those lines will be helpful..
I am unable to post image on this post. you can check/download the image from the following link 
http://i59.tinypic.com/35n69mp.png

Comment: no idea. nothing looks wrong with it, except i would put the `gr.FillRegion` code in `OnPaint` method as `e.Graphics.FillRegion`. and move `rg` and `mybrush` to member vars. you will need to check `If Not rg Is Nothing` though before you paint.

Comment: I am pretty frustrated with this piece of code. is there any other third party graphics handler that you are aware of other than the standard GDI+ for drawing complex shapes ?

Comment: sorry, never dealt with them. (but you need to do all your painting in `OnPaint` anyways ;p) the only other thing i can think of is the `AddArc` and `AddLine` methods might be out of order, try drawing them in order from point to point. like pu tthe first `AddLine` at the end or something.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.. I will move it to onpaint. I tried all possible combinations with those 4 lines (no change in the generated image). in fact some combinations are worse with thick cross-lines.

Comment: then that prob has something to do with it. try drawing them from point to point as well, since you're drawing some of the lines backwards. could get messy ;o and yea, might be better to use some library, but i have no knowledge of any for such a purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private rg As Region
Private mybrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
    If rg IsNot Nothing Then e.Graphics.FillRegion(mybrush, rg)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim path1 As New GraphicsPath
    path1.StartFigure()
    path1.AddArc(120.0F, 120.0F, 560.0F, 560.0F, 10.0F, 45.0F)
    path1.AddArc(100.0F, 100.0F, 600.0F, 600.0F, 55.0F, -45.0F)
    path1.CloseFigure()
    rg = New Region(path1)
    Invalidate()
End Sub
```

there we go, fixed ;p

as a note: path will fill in the points, the lines are unnecessary.

Comment: well I did all combinations with the 4 line. we can have a total of 4! = 24 combinations. here is what i found : out of 24 combinations 4 combinations produced only 1 unintended cross line artifact, another 4 combinations produced 2 cross line artifact. rest of all combinations are horrible.

Comment: Thank-you.. It seems to be fixed.. let me play with the angles a little-bit to check weather i can apply it to all kinds of similar graphic objects. will get back to you soon..

Comment: @user3562495 fixed it again, hehe ;p basically, drawing the second arc from 55 degrees, back down to 10 degrees.

Comment: thank-you once again.. works for all variants of that graphic object .. you saved me a lot of time..

Comment: @user3562495 np, some interesting implications here. means you can draw a triangle, parallelogram or trapezoid with only 2 lines. any quadrilateral actually ;p

Comment: yes, in fact this will make my code more efficient by removing a lot of unnecessary codes ..